# How do you set up ToB maneuver macros for Roll20?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat-maneuver, tome-of-battle, roll20

I'm using Roll20, and I'm trying to figure out how to set up macros for Tome of Battle maneuvers so I can put them in my macro bar to speed things up. However, I have no idea how to set up macros.

Has anyone already made some? Does anyone know enough about macros and Tome of Battle maneuvers that they can tell me how to go about it?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you need, are you looking for one macro that allows you to pick a Maneuver and post it to chat, or an attack macro that includes (one or all) Maneuvers and modifies your attack(s) appropriately? The *massive* amount of Maneuvers would make this difficult, especially if you wanted it to change with which Maneuvers you have prepared. I could do a huge text drop of every single Maneuver, but it wouldn't account for your base to-hit and damage...